# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx) $$ converge?

Or whether the sum can be expressed in another form?

Comment: Depends what $x$ is. More interesting is if $x=\pi$ is the only value for which it converges. My hunch is that it is.

Comment: If $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, then all the terms are $0$ so the series converges to $0$. If not, then IIRC it diverges because the sequence of terms doesn't converge $0$.

Comment: You can try this- if $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n \not= 0$ then the series diverges.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I too have that same hunch for $x\neq m\pi| \forall m\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: This series is divergent (for $x$ not a multiple of $\pi$) but may be regularized (for example by replacing it with $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx)e^{-n\epsilon}\ $) to get :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx)=\frac 1{2\,\tan(x/2)}$$

Comment: for $x$ not a multiple of $\pi$ and $0$ else.

Answer (score 5):

If $x/\pi\in \mathbb Z$ then $\sin nx=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and the series converges.

If $x/\pi \not \in \mathbb Z$ the sequence $(\sin nx)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ does not converge to $0$ so the series diverges.

PROOF. Let $x/\pi \not \in \mathbb Z.$ Then $\sin x \ne 0.$ Suppose by contradiction that $(\sin nx )_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $0.$

Let $r\in (0,\frac {1}{4}|\sin x|)$ such that $\forall y\;(|\sin y|<r\implies |\cos y|>\frac {3}{4}).$ Let $n_0$ satisfy $\forall n\geq n_0\;(|\sin nx|<r).$

Then $|\sin n_0x|<r$ and $|\sin (n_0+1)x|<r.$ But then $|\cos n_0x|>\frac {3}{4}$  and we have  $$\frac {1}{4} |\sin x|>r>|\sin (n_0+1)x|=$$ $$=|\sin x \cos n_0x +\cos x \sin n_0x|\geq$$ $$\geq |\sin x \cos n_0x|-|\cos x \sin n_0x|>$$ $$>\frac {3}{4} |\sin x|- |1\cdot \sin n_0x|>$$ $$>\frac {3}{4}|\sin x|-r>$$ $$>\frac {3}{4}|\sin x|-\frac {1}{4}|\sin x|=$$ $$=\frac {1}{2}|\sin x|$$  implying $\frac {1}{4}|\sin x|>\frac {1}{2}|\sin x|,$ which is impossible.

The idea is that when $\sin nx$ is very near $0,$ then  $nx$ is very near an integer multiple of $\pi$ so $|\sin (n+1)x|$ is very near $|\sin x|.$ This could be clearer in the proof with sharper  restrictions on $r,$ so that $|\sin n_0x|$ is nearly $0$ and $|\cos n_0x|$ is nearly $1.$

Comment: Intuitively the statement $\forall y\;(|\sin(y)|<r\implies |\cos(y)|>\frac {3}{4})$ is clear, but how can I show it rigorously? Do we use continuity? My idea would be like: We find a $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $|y-\pi k|<\delta_1$ we have $|\cos(y)|>\frac{3}{4}$ and we have $\delta_2$ such that $|y-\pi k|<\delta_2$ we have $|\sin(y)|<r$; where $y\neq \pi k$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we take $\delta:=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ and only take those $y$ which satisfy $|y-\pi k|<\delta$.

Comment: @Philipp . $|\sin y|<r<|\sin x|/4\le 1/4\implies |\sin y|<1/4\implies \cos^2 y=1-\sin^2 y>1-1/4^2>(3/4)^2$... BTW I should have said "Let $r\in (0, |\sin x|/4).$ Then $\forall y\,(|\sin y|<r\implies |\cos y|>3/4.$" which means the same but is better phrased.

Answer (score 2):

Convergence of the series depends on $x$. For example, it converges for $x=0$ or $x=\pi$ but not for $x=\pi/2$ (which causes oscillating partial sums).

However, by using complex numbers you can rewrite the series in another form. Note that $$\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}nx}=\cos(nx) + \mathrm{i}\sin (nx)$$
So, for a partial sum we have (I've set the summation index $n$ to start from zero) $$\sum_{n=0}^N\sin(nx)=\mathrm{Im}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^N\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}nx}\right\}$$

The RHS summation is a geometric series, that is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^N\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}nx}&=\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}\right)^n\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(N+1)x}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}-1}
\end{align}
Thus

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^N\sin(nx)&=\mathrm{Im}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^N\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}nx}\right\}\\
&=\mathrm{Im}\left\{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(N+1)x}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}-1}\right\}\\
&=\frac1{2\mathrm{i}}\left( \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(N+1)x}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}-1} -\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}(N+1)x}-1}{\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x}-1} \right)\\
&=\frac1{2\mathrm{i}}\left( \frac{ \left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x}\right)+\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}Nx}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}Nx}\right)-\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(N+1)x}-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}(N+1)x}\right)  }{2-\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}+\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}x}\right)} \right)\\
&=\frac1{2\mathrm{i}}\frac{2\mathrm{i}\sin x+2\mathrm{i}\sin(Nx)-2\mathrm{i}\sin((N+1)x)}{2-2\cos x}\\
&=\frac12 \frac{\sin x+\sin(Nx)-\sin((N+1)x)}{1-\cos x}
\end{align}
By converting the trigonometric sum to product, we'll have
$$\sum_{n=0}^N\sin(nx)=\frac12 \frac{\sin x-2\sin\left(\frac12 x \right)\cos\left(\frac{2N+1}2 x\right)}{1-\cos x}$$

Comment: So? What's the conclusion?

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a conclusion.

Comment: i upvoted because your derivation is insightful for the OP, but you could show directly that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin(nx) = 0$ iff $x = k \pi$, so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx)$ diverges whenever $x \ne k \pi$

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. For example when $x = 2\pi$ then $\lim \cos((2N+1)x/2) = 0$. Besides it could be the case that the limit with the cos doesn't exist, but since there's a $\sin(x/2)$ in front of it the limit of the whole thing could exist anyway.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I meant for $x$ values within $[0,2\pi)$. However, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @user1952009 You're right about the divergence proof, but the OP has also asked for a closed form expression.

Comment: A closed-form for $0+0+0+0$ ?

Comment: And with $x = \pi$ it converges.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi. It should say that $\cos ((2N+1)x/2)$ does not converge unless $\cos (x/2)=0.$  But if $\cos (x/2)=0$ then $x/\pi$ is an integer and $  \sin (nx)=0$ for all $n.$ Conclusion: The series converges only if $x/\pi$ is an integer and all the terms are $0.$

Comment: The problem is with the conclusion part which I now prefer to omit it.

Comment: @user1952009 Obviously, not! I've already mentioned to the partial sum. Please read.